# Understanding and creating Xcode storyboard XML

Tags: xml, xcode, uistoryboard

I like to fully understand the generated XML-file from the Xcode storyboards. So that I can create the file by myself. Unfortunately I can't find a good reference by Apple of how to do it. And after that, is there a way to automatically create a storyboard from the XML-file?

**Answer to your question:**
I'm currently working on a project where I have to create an XML-file from outside Xcode and load this XML-file via an API in an app which creates a new view

Thanks in advance!